# How to bind multiple table to single dataset in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, repeat, export-to-pdf

I am trying to repeat the table data for showing 2 list based on in-out time. So I have copy-paste the table and applied filter function based on in-out time to single dataset. I can view two table in report output as it is but when exporting to PDF table gets overlapped on each other. Also filter seems to get applied to only one table.

How we can tackle PDF export issue?

What are best way to repeat table using single dataset?

Comment: in tablix properties on general tab select  "add a page break after" if you applied filters on dataset level the data should be the same on both tables.

Comment: Even after page break pdf export and filter is not working

Answer (score 0):

Insert a list into the report.

If you can group the row group on something that will generate two rows then brilliant - you will only need one tablix in the list.

If that is not possible, group the row group on 1. Then insert a new row group adjacent below, also grouped on 1. On the new row that has appeared in the list, insert a new rectangle. Now you can past a copy of the tablix into each rectangle, and page break on the row groups instead of the tables.

The groups & rectangles will prevent overlapping when exporting to PDF.